# Qualtrics Prototype Javascript Event.observe not triggering

Tags: javascript, prototype, qualtrics

I'm trying to write a script to count the number of times a key is pressed in qualtrics, which uses prototype javascript. However, event.on or event.observe only seem to trigger after I click on the window somewhere. Am I using the method incorrectly, or is there someway I can simulate a click to work around this? Thank you.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var counter = 0;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Practice",counter);

Event.on(document,'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 49: // '1' was pressed
    choiceID = 1;
    break;
  }
  if (choiceID) {
    counter = counter+1;
    alert(counter);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Practice",counter);
}
});
});
```

Would also appreciate advice on displaying the variable counter on qualtrics using javascript. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding window.focus(); before event.observe did the trick!

Incidentally, to add a display in qualtrics, just use read only form and update its value using javascript.